# How to stop printf from printing escape codes in shell script?

Tags: bash, terminal, shell-script, bash-scripting

When I run a simple shell script with the following code:

```
#!/bin/sh 
printf "\e[32m Hello World\n"
```

I get

\e[32m Hello World

as output as opposed to a green Hello World output.

Comment: I tried this command and it works just fine for me.

Comment: it doesnt work if i run it as part of a shell script

Answer (score 5):

[`printf`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/printf) doesn't understand `\e`; you need to use `\033`.  Note that `printf` is also a `bash` builtin; that one has GNU extensions including `\e`, but unless you specifically request your script be run by `/bin/bash` you will usually get the POSIX one.